# Is a additional ORDER BY neccessary if you use RANK()?

Tags: mysql, sql

based on this website:
https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-rank-function/
There is his code:

```
    [![SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        product_id,
        product_name,
        brand_id,
        list_price,
        RANK () OVER ( 
            PARTITION BY brand_id
            ORDER BY list_price DESC
        ) price_rank 
    FROM
        production.products
) t
WHERE price_rank <= 3;][1]][1]
```

Usually when using

```
PARTITION BY brand_id
ORDER BY list_price DESC
```

in the OVER() statement, it does all the order already of the columns "brand_id" and "list_price". So my question: Is an extra

> ORDER BY()

statement outside of the

> RANK()

statement neccessary if you want the columns "brand_id" and "list_price" ordered?

Comment: Rank needs an order in the window specification to make any sense, and without an order for the outer query the order will be indeterminate, so kind of?  Your question may make more sense of you explain what causes you to ask.

Comment: Ohh, I just seen in a book that the author uses an ORDER BY() inside the rank() query and outside again for the same column and I was confused.

Comment: Good question. Definitively YES. I remember I had the same confusion back in the day when I was learning window functions. The ORDER BY inside the RANK() function serves one purpose (assigning rank numbers), while the ORDER BY of the whole query serves a different purpose (sorting the resulting rows).

Comment: "... it does all the order already of the columns "brand_id" and "list_price"..." -- not true. This is just a coincidence, that may change at any time without notice.